# How to user-input image to div

Tags: javascript, filereader

I want to add the input file from html as a image inside a div however I don't want to use get element buy class name because I have multiple divs and for each one I want to add special image. if I use any selector the image will be added to each div
any one can help . Thanks

I use this, this will change the image to all div having this class but I want to add a special img to each div

edit: iam creating a new div each time and i want for each div I created to add a special img

here is the full code to create new div and to add pic

> mainspan.onclick = () => {   // mainspan is button used to create div
>
> let div = document.createElement("div");
> div.classList.add("main-dd");   let button =
> document.createElement("button");   let img =
> document.createElement("img");   img.classList.add("currentimg");
> div.appendChild(img);   button.classList.add("btnaddinfo");
> button.innerHTML = "Add item";   button.addEventListener("click", ()
> => {
> addinfo.style.display = "block"; // the menue to add the new picture   });   div.appendChild(button);
>
> const uploadPictureButton = document.querySelector(".photo-upload");
>
> uploadPictureButton.addEventListener("change", function () {
> displayPicture(this);   });
>
> function displayPicture(input) {
> if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
> var reader = new FileReader();
>
> ```
>   reader.onload = function (e) {
>     document
>       .querySelector(".currentimg")
>       .setAttribute("src", e.target.result);
>   };
>
>   reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
> }   } }; })
> ```
>
> ```
> document.querySelector(".photo-upload");   
> uploadPictureButton.addEventListener("change", function () {
>               displayPicture(this); }); let a; function displayPicture(input) {   if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
>     var reader = new FileReader();
>
>     reader.onload = function (e) {
>       document
>         .querySelector(".currentimg")
>         .setAttribute("src", e.target.result);
>     };
>
>               reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
>
>   } }
> ```

Comment: if you really want to be that specific then add an id to each div and get each element by their id, then proceed to add the img you want to each of them

Comment: @ChrisG thank you but the problem is that i use a button to create a div . then to this new added div Iam trying to add an image , if you understand my issue

Comment: you can give your div an id the moment you create it. Is there a limit for how many divs you can create?

Comment: Please update the question with the code used to create the div with image (even if not working).

Comment: @Yogi can you please check

Comment: Your code has multiple problems and is difficult to fix.  Yet, @BobbyMorelli has provided a good solution to your question.  Please consider accepting his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("change",event=>{
  document.querySelector("img").src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
})
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid: 1fr 1fr / 1fr;
}

img {
  width:4em;
  height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<input type="file"  accept="image/png, image/jpeg"/>
<img/>
```

Comment: Good solution as it avoids all the extra code required by FileReader. +1